# Cloud telephony call forwarding

Tags: cloud, telephony, voice-recording, exotel-api

I am looking for a cloud telephony solution that would allow me to create a routing service. The service would work as follows:

1. The user calls the number,
2. The user makes some menu choices using a dail pad,
3. Based on some data fetched from a DB and the user's choice, a certain number is selected,
4. The user is then routed to that number.

The list of numbers will change perhaps once a day or so. Additionally, I would like to be able to record the calls and have them available for a certain period of time.

It seems to me that what I describe resembles the most a call centre (THOUGH in this case the service provided would be something else).

**Question**: Do you know of any cloud telephony service that would fit this use-case? What is the pricing model for this kind of service generally? Can it be per-call or per-call-minute flat model? Any useful keywords to use?

Have been googling this for hours now and still without luck. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at twilio and OpenVBX, by twilio itself for this if you're in the US. OpenVBX is pretty versatile and has a lot more to offer than what you've mentioned. You can also look at plivo

If you're in India or Southeast Asia , you can look at [Exotel](https://exotel.com)

Disclaimer: I work at Exotel.